# Testing subscription in Android

Tags: android, android-billing

I am using in app billing V3. I am adding the subscription feature. I couldn't tell from the documentation as it was not clear enough, Can I use the static response codes for testing subscription? If not, how do I test cancelling and resubscription ..etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static responses don’t work with subscriptions. The only way to test it is to actually purchase a monthly or a yearly subscription.

If you purchased this subscription and want to test it again you have two choices:

- wait until subscription expires (month/year + trial period)
- do a factory reset again and use another test user